# Probability of visiting state $s_1$ of a Markov chain more than $N$ times in $L$ steps.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Assume we have a two-state Markov chain, with $s_1$ and $s_0$ denoting the two states. The initial state of the Markov chain is either $s_1$ or $s_0$ with probability $p_1$ or $p_0$, respectively. The transition probability between states $s_i$ and $s_j$ is $p_{ij}$.

**My question is, given the initial state probability $p_1$ for state $s_1$, which is the probability that after $L$ steps, state $s_1$ has been visited more than $N$ times? Notice that remaining in state $s_1$ counts as an other visit to this state.**

I thought that this was a quite straight forward question, but after some research in probability and stochastic processes books I found no theorem with this result. I tried to proof it my self, but I the solution looks like being quite tedious.

I would really appreciate if somebody can point me the right direction in how to calculate this probability.

cheers

Pol

Comment: Can you clarify: is remaining in state 1 counted as visiting state 1 or not?

Comment: @DaleM I have edited the post. Now is clear that remaining in state $s_1$ counts as a visit.

Answer (score 3):

This is my answer to my own question. I wanted to get an expression easy to work with, but this is the best I got.

The question is to compute the probability $P(N_1 \geq N | L)$ that is the probability that the number of visits to state $s_1$ (denoted by $N_1$) is larger than $N$ after $L$ state transitions. If state $s_1$ is revisited from state $s_1$ this is counted as an another visit. I count the visits to state $s_1$ as the number of state transitions that start from $s_1$; that is, the number of times that transitions $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ and $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ occur.

I denote by $P_1(n,l|s_i)$ the probability of visiting exactly $n$ times state $s_1$ in $l$ state transitions when the initial state is $s_i$. Then $P(N_1 \geq N | L)$ is
\begin{equation}
P(N_1 \geq N | L)=p_1\sum_{i=N_1}^{L}P_1(i,L|s_1)+p_0\sum_{i=N_1}^{L-1}P_1(i,L|s_0),
\end{equation}

where the second term sums up to $L-1$ only because the initial state is $s_0$. I now compute $P_1(i,l|s_1)$

\begin{equation}
P_1(i,l|s_1)=\sum_{j=1}^{l-i+1}  \underbrace{p_{11}^{i-j}p_{10}^{j}\binom{i-1}{j-1}}_{A0}  \underbrace{p_{01}^{j-1}p_{00}^{l-i-j+1}\binom{l-i}{j-1}}_{B0}+ \sum_{j=1_{l>i}}^{l-i}   \underbrace{p_{11}^{i-j}p_{10}^{j}\binom{i}{j}}_{A1}\underbrace{p_{01}^{j}p_{00}^{l-i-j}\binom{l-i-1}{j-1}}_{B_1},
\end{equation}

where in $A0$-$B0$ and $A1$-$B1$ the final state is assumed to be $s_0$ and $s_1$, respectively.  First I explain $A0$-$B0$. To visit state $s_1$ a total of $i$ times is it necessary to have exactly a total of $i$ $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ and/or $s_1 \rightarrow s_1$ state transitions. In particular,  there are  $i-j$ and $j$ $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ and $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ state transitions, respectively. Since the final state is $s_0$, and  $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ transition occurs $j$ times, there must be a total of $j-1$ $s_0 \rightarrow s_1$  state transitions. The total number of state transitions is $l$, then the total number of $s_0 \rightarrow s_0$ state transitions must be $l-j-i+1$. Now lets focus on $A0$, for each  $s_0 \rightarrow s_1$ transition a set of $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ state transitions may occur (note 1),  the total number of $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ transition sets is $j$ (i.e., number of $s_0 \rightarrow s_1$ transitions plus one). In total there must be $i-j$   $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ state transitions spread over $j$ $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ transition sets, the total number of possible combinations is the is the weak composition (note 2)  of $j$ naturals that sum up to $i-j$ (note 3). $B0$ is obtained similarly, for each $s_1\rightarrow s_0$ transition there might be a set of $s_0\rightarrow s_0$ transitions. Hence there are a total $l-i-j+1$ $s_0\rightarrow s_0$ transitions spread over  $j$ $s_0\rightarrow s_0$ transitions sets.  Hence, the total number of possible combinations  is the weak composition of $j$ natural numbers that sum up to $l-i-j+1$.

Now I will explain $A1$-$B1$. In this case the final state is $s_1$, and the number of $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ state transitions is the same as the number of $s_0 \rightarrow s_1$ state transitions. The total number of  $s_1 \rightarrow s_0$ and $s_0 \rightarrow s_1$ state transitions is $j$, the total number of $s_1 \rightarrow s_1$ is $i-j$, and the total number of $s_0 \rightarrow s_0$ is $l-j-i$. The total number of $s_1 \rightarrow s_1$ state transition sets is $j+1$, and the total  number of $s_0 \rightarrow s_0$ state transition sets is $j$. The total number possible combinations of having $i-j$ $s_1 \rightarrow s_1$ state transitions spread over $j+1$ transitions sets is the weak combination of $j+1$ natural numbers that add to $i-j$. Following the same rationale, the  total number possible combinations of having $l-j-i$ $s_0 \rightarrow s_0$ state transitions spread over $j$ transitions sets is the weak combination of $j$ natural numbers that add to $l-j-i$.

To compute $P_1(i,l|s_0)$ we can make use of $P_1(i,l|s_1)$,

\begin{equation}
P_1(i,l|s_0)=\sum_{j=1}^{l-i}p_{00}^{j-1}p_{01}P_1(i,l-j|s_1),
\end{equation}

where the term $p_{00}^{j-1}p_{01}$ corresponds to first transition probability from $s_0$ to $s_1$.

**It is still needed to check all possible cases, and the limits of the sums. However, I think that this is pretty much it.**

**Notes**

1. (note 1)A state transition set, is a group of transitions that occur
   one after the other, the sets can be empty.
2. (note 2)The weak composition is the total number of possible combinations of summing
   up any $j$ natural number (including $0$) so that they sum up to
   $m$, and is given by $\binom{m+j-1}{j-1}$.
3. (note 3)An explanation for that is the following: each time we go from $s_0$ to state $s_1$ we can stay in $s_1$ for $n$ transitions or to go to $s_0$ directly. In total we must have $i-j$  $s_1\rightarrow s_1$ state transitions, so the sum of all the $n$'s (one for each time we go from $s_0$ to $s_1$) must be equal to $i-j$, the total number of possible combinations of $n$'s is the weak composition of $j$ natural numbers that sum up to $i-j$.

Comment: Hi, So I started looking at the same problem few days back and to my surprise I found no work on this problem. I just wanted to find $P_1(n, l | s_i)$, and as I was exploring you formula see that it fails in many cases. The second part A1-B1 works in most cases except the times you have to summation is different. But the first part I think is not correct e.g. P(2,6 | s_1), the summation will go to 5, which is not the case it must only go to 3(I have counted them manually), otherwise you get invalid values in the combinations. Have you corrected the formula, I might be wrong so any help is app.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in state 1 then the chance that you will move to state 2 is a geometric distribution with parameter $p_{21}$. Similarly a change from 1 to 2 is a geometric distribution with parameter $p_{12}.

If you start in State 1 (assuming this counts as a visit), then to visit more than $N$ times you need to leave this state and return at least $N$ times. Alternatively, if you start in State 2, you need to leave this state at least $N+1$ times and return $N$ times.

Now the sum of geometric distributions is a negative binomial distribution so your probability is

$$P(n>N)={p_1 \sum_{k=N}^{L-N}NB(N,p_{21})\sum_{j=k}^{L-N}NB(N,p_{12})} + {(1-p_1) \sum_{k=N}^{L-N}NB(N,p_{21})\sum_{j=k}^{L-(N+1)}NB(N,p_{12})} $$

Where $NB$ is the negative binomial probability for $k$ and $j$ as applicable.

Note this is the solution to the question as originally posed, where staying in state $p_1$ **does not** count as a visit.

For the revised question, the problem can be restated as *not* being in State 2 for more than $L-N$ steps. A modification of the above should get you there.

Comment: Could you explain the appearance of products of the form $NB(k,p)NB(k,q)$?

Comment: @DaleM  Sorry that the question was not clearly explained. Now I think that if we consider that remaining in state $s_1$ counts also as a visit, this answer is not valid any more. I would try to came up with an expression using the negative binomial distribution. Any further comment from your side would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Did I agree, there are some parts that need to be clarified, but I prefer to stick to the original question of the post, rather to try solving this other.

Comment: @Did I have revised the answer because the original was a) unclear and b) wrong.

Comment: Maybe not yet the ideal answer... Some indices $k$ and $j$ simply do not appear in the sums.

Comment: @Did - I believe these combinations represent a 0 probability of $N$ visits

Comment: Once again: you are summing over $k$ and $j$ quantities which do not depend on $k$ and $j$.

Comment: @Did - $k$ and $j$ are the $Pr(X=k/j)$ for the probability mass function of $NB$. Please edit the answer if there is a clearer way to express this.